# Gensim FastText - KeyError: "word not in vocabulary"

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I was having trouble with the "most_similar" call in a FastText model, from my understanding, Fasttext should be able to obtain results for words that aren't in the vocabulary, but I'm getting a "Not in Vocabulary" error, even when prior to saving and loading, the call was perfectly fine.

Here's the code from juypter.

```
import gensim as gensim

model = gensim.models.FastText(my_sentences, size=100, window=5, min_count=3, workers=4, sg=1)
model.wv.most_similar(positive=['iPhone 6'])
```

Returns

```
[('iPhone7', 0.942690372467041),
('iPhone7.', 0.9395840764045715),
('iPhone5s', 0.9379133582115173),
('iPhone6s', 0.9338586330413818),
('iPhone5S', 0.9335439801216125),
('iPhone5.', 0.9318809509277344),
('iPhone®', 0.9314558506011963),
('iPhone6', 0.9268479347229004),
('iPhone4s', 0.9223971366882324),
('iPhone5', 0.9212019443511963)]
```

So far so good, now I save the model.

```
model.wv.save_word2vec_format("example_fasttext.txt", binary=False)
```

Then load it up again:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
new_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('example_fasttext.txt', binary=False, limit=50000)
```

Then I do the exact most_similar call from the model I just loaded:

```
new_model.most_similar(positive=['iPhone 6'])
```

But results now are:

```
KeyError: "word 'iPhone 6' not in vocabulary"
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probaly in the `limit` parameter of the `load_word2vec_format` method. What you are doing here is loading the model only for the 50000 most frequent words. If `iPhone 6` does not appear enough times, you are not loading it.

Try with

```
new_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('example_fasttext.txt', binary=False)
```

Comment: Hey Etienne, it makes sense. I just tried it to make sure that was problem, but I am still getting the "not in vocabulary" error. Kinda weird huh, would it be vectors are generalized, and your not really loading back a Fasttext model anymore?

Comment: I am not familiar with Fasttext but you should try to save your model with the `save` [method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.save) instead and load it with the `load_fasttext_format` [method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format) as advised on the docs

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as you, and I think I am starting to understand what's going on.

Basically, when you save your model as a `.txt` or as a `.vec`, you are only saving the word-vectors ; *not* the n-grams (saved in the binary version of your model), which allow you to generalize / approximate out-of-vocabulary words.

I suggest you save your model with:

```
your_fasttext_model.save(file_path)
```